# Archiving text log files in postgresql

Tags: perl, postgresql, dbi

We are writing a testing framework from scratch using Perl. Each test case writes a log file and we are planning to archive the resulting log files created by each test case for reporting purposes.

Now we are using PostgreSQL database for storing the results. Now how do I archive the text log file in PostgreSQL database? I googled and found out that `bytea` datatype can be used to store files in binary format. If I do so how do i retrieve it back as text?.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If your log files are text files, then you should use the [`TEXT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html) datatype to store them. If the log files are binary (or, perhaps, compressed text files), then you'd want to use [`BYTEA`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html). In either case, you can INSERT and SELECT them just like any other column type when using DBI. If they're really large then you might want to play with the [`LongReadLen`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#LongReadLen) DBI parameter and read the [DBI manual section on BLOBs](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#Handling_BLOB_/_LONG_/_Memo_Fields).